# Dynamically allocated C array suddenly getting modified

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, undefined-behavior, realloc

I currently have a little project written in C here:

https://github.com/Nirma/clox/tree/virtual_machine

And have an issue where sometimes when this code runs:

```
int addValue(Chunk *chunk, Value value) {
    ValueArray *array = &chunk->values;
    if (array->capacity < array->count + 1) {
        array->capacity = GROW_CAPACITY(array->capacity);
        array->values = realloc(array->values, array->capacity);
    }

    array->values[array->count] = value;
    array->count++;
    return chunk->values.count - 1;
}
```

Another seemingly unrelated structure gets affected.

This code runs as expected but for some reason when these lines get uncommented:

```
    // location = addValue(&chunk, 500);
    // writeChunk(&chunk, OP_CONST, 1);
    // writeChunk(&chunk, location, 150);
```

the byte code array `code` held by `Chunk` gets corrupted but the address of the array remains the same.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Chunk chunk;
    
    initVM();
    initChunk(&chunk);
    int location;
    location = addValue(&chunk, 50);
    writeChunk(&chunk, OP_CONST, 123);
    writeChunk(&chunk, location, 123);
    
    
    location = addValue(&chunk, 150);
    writeChunk(&chunk, OP_CONST, 123);
    writeChunk(&chunk, location, 123);
    
    writeChunk(&chunk, OP_ADD, 123);
    writeChunk(&chunk, OP_NEGATE, 123);
    
    // location = addValue(&chunk, 500);
    // writeChunk(&chunk, OP_CONST, 1);
    // writeChunk(&chunk, location, 150);
    
    interpretChunk(&chunk);
    return 0;
}
```

I apologize for not summarizing the issue better but I'm not sure which area of the code is at fault so I posted a link to the project.

I am running this via Clang on Xcode on an arm64 machine.

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

I tried the code posted above and was expecting:

`// location = addValue(&chunk, 500); // writeChunk(&chunk, OP_CONST, 1); // writeChunk(&chunk, location, 150);`

To simply add another instruction to push a constant onto the stack but instead had my bytecode array wiped clean.

Comment: Do not tag C++ if the code is C.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: You haven't specified any types but I'm guessing that `realloc(array->values, array->capacity)` should be `realloc(array->values, array->capacity*sizeof(Value))`. In other words you forgot to adjust the bytes allocated by `realloc` by the size of the elements being allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least this statement

```
array->values = realloc(array->values, array->capacity);
```

shall be rewritten like

```
array->values = realloc(array->values, array->capacity * sizeof( Value ) );
```

Though it would be more safer to use an intermediate pointer like for example

```
Value *tmp = realloc(array->values, array->capacity * sizeof( Value ) );

if ( tmp != NULL )
{
    array->values = tmp;
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes this was it I forgot to multiply the new capacity by `sizeOf(Value)` and since `Value` is larger than 1 byte this did indeed cause issues. Awesome detective work!

Answer (score -1):

> Another seemingly unrelated structure gets affected.

The most common root cause for such mystery failures is heap corruption. The other structure may be already freed, or there could be heap buffer overflow somewhere.

If the problem is reproducible, you can use debugger [watchpoint](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) to find out what code *writes* to the other structure.

Also [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) is your friend.